# Apart from Union , Union all and Pivot in MS- Sql server can I combine two columns into one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having a result set like

```
Col1:    Col2

a         b

c         d
```

I want result set like

```
a

b

c

d
```

Without using Union, Union all and Pivot.

Comment: I suggest normalising your tables so that data is atomic.

Comment: What's the problem with the mentioned ways?

Comment: Is this some kind of homework or why can't you use Union or pivot

Comment: a b c d once per row suggests the data structure is not normalised. Also, before your edit, it looked like a and b was in the same column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT T.x
FROM table
     CROSS APPLY (
         VALUES (Col1), (Col2)
     ) AS T(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unpivot`.

```
select value from yourtable
    unpivot (value for field in (col1,col2)) u
```